# Why am I getting an error when using button_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The line of code giving me the error is:

```
<%= button_to 'Search', static_pages/gallery %>
```

The error is:

> Undefined local variable or method `static_pages'

Here are my routes:

```
match "/home" => "static_pages#home"
match "/gallery" => "static_pages#gallery"

get "static_pages/home"
get "static_pages/gallery"
post "static_pages/gallery"
```

Comment: Just to give you a nudge, you've provided basically no context for what you're doing, so it's going to be impossible to give you a specific answer. Chances are it's that you have used `link_to` to create a link to something that doesn't have a route or controller action to match it. Give more specifics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is invalid syntax:

```
<%= button_to 'Search', static_pages/gallery %>
```

Ruby will look for variable `static_pages` and `gallery`, which don't exist. It should be a string instead:

```
<%= button_to 'Search', 'static_pages/gallery' %>
```